# Does checked affects onChange Event?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Running the following test for a react JS using Jest /  Enzyme

```
it("should call onChange function ", () => {
  baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
  wrapper.setState([{col:{
   Name:{}
  },
}]);
 wrapper.update() 
 wrapper.find('#test').at(0).simulate('change',[{ col: { Name:{} } }])
});
```

Here is where onChange event is being called

```
</div>
  <input
  class='settings-input' 
  id='test' type='checkbox' 
  checked={this.state[col.Name]} onChange={(e) => {this.setState({[col.Name]: !this.state[col.Name]})}} />
 </div>
```

Does checked affect my test not to pass ? At the moment method cannot find any node.
I also added an id for testing purpose

Thank you

Comment: is your `wrapper.setState` correct on the test file? Where and how are you getting the `col.Name` below?

Comment: That is all  the information that I have.. wrapper state is on my test. Below baseProps